# Rstudio opens files in a network drive with massive delays

Tags: r, windows, filesystems, rstudio

I have been using RStudio for many years now; for some reason it takes a long time (10-15 seconds) for RStudio (in Windows) to open a file from a network drive. Other applications such as Notepad, native R, MS Word have no issues, clearly indicating this is not just a network latency issue. Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution? I'm using version 0.99.903. I have [asked the same in the rstudio forums too](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203474536-RStudio-very-slow-saving-script-to-network-drive), but there has been no response.

Comment: For me it happens once in a while which makes me think my problem was a network one. Try reading the file from an R script or other R gui to see if Rstudio specific.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. There are no issues opening the file in Rgui. Now that you mentioned  I tried using file.edit() to open the same file and there are no delays. It only happens if I use File->Open File -> (Navigate to file) method. Quite strange.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to ask this question on the RStudio forums ...

Comment: Other users have reported similar issues in the Rstudio forums - and I did ask the question there as well - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203474536-RStudio-very-slow-saving-script-to-network-drive  - the response is not very swift from those forums. Its been an open issue for the last 2 years

Comment: OK.  When you've asked in other venues I think it's worth stating that in your question (and linking to the question) ...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I made the necessary changes.